# Problem with graphics on ubuntu gnome 3

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

Okay so I have a weird graphics problem on my lenovo thinkpad yoga s2. There is a strange lag between two areas of my screen. I'm sorry I couldn't take a great picture, when I tried to do a snapshot on the computer the glitch wouldn't show so I had to take a picture with my phone. So I checked what graphic card I had with lspci and here is the log:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I have installed the Intel Graphics Installer tool and installed all the packages but the bug is still there. I don't really know what to do and don't quite know where to look, so I'm calling to the community to help me figure this one out. Here are the images:

- Horizontal line problem

  [image: image 1]
- Top of the screen horizontal line

  [image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after posting my first question I will now attempt to post my first answer. So the phenomenon is called "tearing" and after looking at this link on the ArchLinux wiki

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Configuration

It was mentioned that you could create a configuration file and add an option called tearfree.

So the steps are:

1. create directory xorg.conf.d inside /etc/X11/
2. create a file named 20-intel.conf inside /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and insert these lines inside:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
       Driver      "intel"
       Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   EndSection
   ```

Voila! No more screen tearing!